# How to save a bitmap after applying effects

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, android-internal-storage

I have some buttons and one image view. I load a photo from gallery,the photo is displayed on image view. For every button,there is on click method to apply that applies one of the effects for the image. There is another button,that is for saving the photo on internal storage. I want to save the photo after one of the effects is applied. I searched,but I just find how to save the photo without effect . Does somebody know how with the on click method to save the image AFTER the effect is applied .

Answer (score 0):

you can simply get the bitmap from `ImageView` by calling this function:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap()
```

and then save your bitmap where you want with in/out streams:

```
private void saveBitmapFromImageView(File destFile, ImageView imageView){

    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap()
    OutputStream os;
    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "saveBitmapFromImageView", e);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
    }
}
```

Edit #1:

`IOUtils` is Apache commons lib, add to your gradle:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Comment: for some reason , it doesn't resolve symbol IOUtilis.. Can you be more specific,which code to put in my onclick method ?

Comment: IOUtils is an apache commons lib that helps you to work with streams more efficient

Comment: I have in onCreate()  showPhoto.setImageBitmap(bm);..then I have some buttons when I click them with onClick method they apply some effects over bitmap. Then with the onclick method I wanna save the image with effects on internal storage. Can you explain in details.? Because I'm trying ,but I cannot find a solution.